# What is the meaning of "Olha a Pedra"?

Tags: expressões, tradução, expressões-equivalentes

I've been following a few Brazilian music artists lately and something they seem to say on social media is "Olha a Pedra".

I translated it using google translate and it said it means "Look at the Stone", but that doesn't mean anything significant without context in the USA. Does it mean something different in Brazil? Is it something cultural that I don't understand?

Some usage examples:

- https://soundcloud.com/ergyrge8greh/olha-a-pedra
  (the music artist who owns this account is fairly well known and recently encrypted the song titles on this archival account, but the URL still has the song name.  this is more of a novelty thing almost.  comments on his main songs on youtube contain the phrase 'Olha a Pedra' as well, but I don't want to disclose the artist's name for his sake.  I also want to note that he makes all other songs on that account private BUT Olha a Pedra right before he releases a song on his main alias)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb7lRInEa6c&t=19
  The DJ introduces a song with a call "olha a pedra!"

those are the two main examples, but a quick [youtube search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=olha%20a%20pedra) shows several results that have lots of views.

Comment: I'm looking forward to what folks will answer to this question. Could you include [an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lep1nNb8OpE) of the songs please?

Comment: @bad_coder added examples

Comment: FYI, that's Brazilian Portuguese. The expression isn't used in the European variants.

Comment: There is no reason not to give the name of a recording artist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Olha a pedra" não é uma expressão conhecida ou usada em português.
A palavra "pedra", entretanto, é muito utilizada como significado de "Pedra de crack", ou seja, o narcótico, o qual é fumado, assim como a maconha.
Na música específica do DJ Cleiton Rasta, ao ler a letra, vemos que a temática da música é justamente o uso de drogas, como se vê no trecho "O nego é cabeça de gelo, Chama! Acende um pá nois fumá".
Meu entendimento, portanto, é que a chamada se refere a pedra de crack.

Pedra: S.F: Droga, pedra de crack

Exemplo: *"Ele adora fumar pedra e por isso está ferrado."*

Comment: This seems to make sense.  However, the music artist who had the "olha a pedra" song posted an instagram story using the word "pedra" that had an image of someone holding a rock, implying it would be thrown: https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/17848588796163084/

Comment: Maybe they do that to disguise the real meaning... to avoid issues with the Law. I recommend the site dicionarioinformal.com.br to check brasilian slang or regionalism. Its a wiki-based dictionary with very accurate meanings.

Comment: https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/pedra/

Answer (score 2):

In the music context *pedra* or *pedrada* means something like "big hit" in english. It may be used to refer to rave songs or fast paced electronic music.